# Can't seem to submit collection_select and receiving Unpermitted parameter: :hero_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

Sorry for the messy post, my first time posting. I have been trying to get this collection submit to work, but every time I press create report button I have it goes back to the screen and puts out Unpermitted parameter: :hero_id in the rails server terminal.

Model

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  validates :subject, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 100 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 300 }

  belongs_to :requester
  has_and_belongs_to_many :heros
end
```

View/Form

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-10">
         <% if @report.errors.any? %>
         <h2>The following errors prevented the article from being saved</h2>
         <ul>
            <% @report.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
         </ul>
         <% end %>
         <%= form_with(model: @report, class: "shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-dark rounded", local: true) do |f| %>
         <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :subject, class: "col-2 col-form-label text-light" %>
            <div class="col-10">
               <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Subject of Report" %>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :description, class: "col-2 col-form-label text-light" %>
            <div class="col-10">
               <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Description of Issue" %>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :hero, class: "col-2 col-form-label text-light" %>
            <div class="col-10">
               <%= f.collection_select(:hero_ids, Hero.all, :id, :hero_name, {prompt: "Select a Hero"}, {:required => true}) %>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="btn-toolbar p-2 mb-2 row justify-content-center">
            <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
         </div>
         <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
         <%= link_to '[ Cancel and return to reports listing ]', reports_path, class: "text-info" %>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
def report_params
    #byebug
 params.require(:report).permit(:subject, :description, hero_ids: [])
end
```

Console

```
(byebug) params.require(:report)
<ActionController::Parameters {"subject"=>"Test report", "description"=>"Test report", "hero_ids"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: Show your params as they appear in your server console.

Comment: Those aren't params as they appear in your console. That is a `Report` instance. Also, please edit your console output into your original question. Code and other information in comments is not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I added what you were requesting for.

Comment: notice how it says `hero_ids` in the params sent over?  If that is the field then change it to match that in the whitelisted parameters (`hero_id` => `hero_ids`)

Comment: @RockwellRice - Need to convert `hero_id: []` to `hero_ids`, yes? `hero_ids: []` will still be incorrect. Also, why does the console read "Unpermitted parameter: :hero_id" when there is clearly no `hero_id` in the params?

Comment: Yes, that's better. Although, it's often better to show a more complete output beginning with `Started GET`... (or whatever the HTTP verb might be).

Comment: @RockwellRice - I changed over the fields to hero_ids and just received this instead. I updated the code above. Unpermitted parameter: :hero_ids

Comment: Can you add the code for the entire form?  There is something off about this setup.

Comment: @RockwellRice - there you go. There is the form.

Comment: You're permitting an array (`hero_ids: []`), but your params has a string (`hero_ids: "1"`). Try changing `hero_ids: []` to `:hero_ids` in your `permit` clause.

Comment: omg, that was staring me in the face! thank you for help you two